# How to use router-link in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, laravel-vue

I am a beginner to `laravel-vue` and I have a problem with `router-link` when I get data from the database to view, all things work correctly, but when I set the `path` to router link, it does not work.

**The error is like:**

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop “to”. Expected String, Object, got Undefined found in ---> RouterLink

**Here is my template code:-**

```
<template>
 <v-card>
   <v-card-title primary-title>
       <div>
           <h3 class="headline mb-0">
               <router-link :to="data.path">{{data.title}}</router-link>
           </h3>
           <div class="grey--text">
               {{data.created_at}}
           </div>
       </div>
   </v-card-title>
   <v-card-text>
      {{data.body}}
   </v-card-text>
 </v-card>
</template>
```

**This is my script:-**

```
<script>

export default {
   props:['data']

}
```

**This is the form template view that I read `questions` inside it:-**

```
<template>
<v-container fluid grid-list-md>
    <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs8>
            <question v-for="question in questions"
            :key="question.path"
            :data=question
            >

            </question>
        </v-flex>
        sidebar  
    </v-layout>
</v-container>
</template>
```

**And this is forum script:-**

```
<script>
import question from './question'
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            questions:{}
        }
    },
   components:{question},
    created(){
        axios.get('/api/question')
        .then(res=> this.questions = res.data.data)
        .catch(error=>console.log(error.response.data))
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello is says its expcting a string or an object ,, but it received an undefinded .
how to debug this ?
you should go back in steps

**1. check the item you accessing maybe console log it :** here it looks fine :to="data.path" but data could be empty or undefined 
**2 . check the prop for changes** :it didnt change 
**3 . check prop passing** `:data=question` aha !: **here is the problem** i think you are missing **quotes** here

it should be `:data="question"`

```
<question v-for="question in questions"
            :key="question.path"
            :data="question"
            >
```

**4. this would be where you check your request** ... so always check your data with console log , how it is formatted what it contains and then use it ,, if its alright than you probably have soime syntax issue

Comment: yes ofc but with the {{  }} ,, so if you dont use those it will display as text ! just add the quotes here and it will work then